# clusterMap doesn't work properly with try block

Tags: r, parallel-processing, try-catch

I found strange problem with clusterMap function from 'parallel' package in R.

Code example:

```
library(parallel);

maxThreads <- max(1, detectCores() - 1);
internalCluster <- makeCluster(maxThreads, homogeneous=FALSE, XDR=FALSE);

modelList <- clusterMap(internalCluster, function(i)
{
    try(1/'a', silent = TRUE);
}, 1:100000, .scheduling = "dynamic");

stopCluster(internalCluster);
```

This code must works correct, but each time I run it, I get an error:

> Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 1e+05 nodes produced errors;
>   first error: Error in 1/"a" : non-numeric argument to binary operator

So,if we change this code a little, it works fine!

```
library(parallel);

maxThreads <- max(1, detectCores() - 1);
internalCluster <- makeCluster(maxThreads, homogeneous=FALSE, XDR=FALSE);

modelList <- parLapply(internalCluster, 1:100000, function(i)
{
    try(1/'a', silent = TRUE);
});

stopCluster(internalCluster);
```

Is this an R code bug? Unfortunately, I can't ask this in R bugzilla directly.((((

Thank you.

Comment: I haven't tried but at a first glance this could indeed be a bug, unless a documented behavior (I can imagine one pretty technical reason for this). I'd recommend you to bring it up on the R-help mailing list. Don't forget to report sessionInfo(). (Even when people are 99.9% sure they've found a bug, the preferred way is always to discuss it on R-help or R-devel first - saving the few people on bugzilla some work)

Comment: HenrikB, could you help me with their mail? I can't find...(((